# .NET Maui Entry Complete With No Return Button on iOS?

Tags: ios, .net, xamarin, maui

I'm using an entry control (.Net 7) with the keyboard type specifically set to numeric only as entering letter text is not necessary and will cause issues as it's sending data to a BT device and is generally just clunky requiring the user to switch. The problem is that there is no return button on this keyboard layout and thus the 'completed' event handler will never fire.

I've tried to use the OnTextChanged handler, which does work as the devs. intended but not for my problem as the entry needs to be captured only once it is fully typed.

Anybody come across a solution for this? It's a non-issue on the Android side of things as the return button is present in a numeric entry.